# JSP compilation by IDEA

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea

I would like to compile my JSP files when I press compile button at IDEA. Is this possible?

Use case:

I am trying to use Dropwizard with JSP support. JSP support is not available and I have to modify to support it. I have two way to provide support. One of them is using already compiled JSP files. That is why at my development environment I wanted to compile JSP files in case a modification.

Comment: What is the use case? It's possible to [enable JSP validation](http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/9752/20130228131253.png) that is performed by compiling them with Jasper.

Comment: IDEA doesn't have a feature to pre-compile JSPs, you will have to use Ant/Maven or some other external tool for this.

Comment: @CrazyCoder As of IntelliJ14, I no longer see anything in the list of validators.